# Include consulting work in CV

Tags: cv, industry

I am now between postdocs and I did some consulting work for a SME. The work was slightly related to my research field (I am a physicist specialized in developing algorithms, and the work I did was to develop an image management system).

In my CV, I included the consulting work in the "Education and experience" section. Would you recommend doing otherwise? Is there any reason why I should leave it out, e.g. to show that I am focused and will do the work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it is good that you have included it, and that you have included it in a separate section (another alternative would be to include yet another section, towards the bottom of your CV, listing "consulting activities", but it certainly falls under an 'experience' heading).  Having some consulting experience under your belt gives you some credibility that a 3rd party finds your insight valuable. If this consulting activity has ended, I might also note as such (e.g., 2015-2016) so as to avoid any hesitation that your time may be shared in the future.